# Copy file and file structure and merge in new directory

Tags: find, cpio

I used the following command line

```
find src -name '*.json' | cpio -pdm lib
```

So it found the json file as in the sceenshot below

[image: screenshot 1]

But then it takes the whole directory structure and places it into the lib folder:

[image: screenshot two]

What I'm aiming for is for the file and its directory files structure (src -> server -> data -> diceware.json) to be merged into the new folder (lib -> server -> data -> diceware.json)

Perhaps somebody can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `find` prints the full path from your current location (ie. including `src`). You need to strip off the first path component, or move further into the directory structure to avoid this.

```
cd src && find . -name '*.json' -print0 | cpio -0pdm ../lib
```

Comment: OSX's `find` does actually [seem to support](http://ss64.com/osx/find.html) the `-print0` flag.

Comment: @terdon Interesting, I thought it was a GNU thing. It seems even cpio on mac has `-0` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
find . -name '*json' | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do 
        mkdir -p lib/$(dirname "$file"); 
        cp "$file" lib/"$(dirname "$file")"
done
```

Or, if your file names can contain newlines:

```
find . -name '*json' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do 
        mkdir -p lib/$(dirname "$file"); 
        cp "$file" lib/"$(dirname "$file")"
done
```